# How to show one message at a time in bootstrapvalidator

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jqbootstrapvalidation

I have added three validation message. when i am clicking on submit button, all three messages are displaying in the div.

Is there any way to show one message at a time(priority vice or which ever comes first.)

code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <input class="form-control" type="password" id="<isprint value="#NewPasswordForm:Password:QualifiedName#">" name="<isprint value="#NewPasswordForm:Password:QualifiedName#">" placeholder="Password" data-bv-notempty="true"
                required data-bv-notempty-message="<istext key="account.user.new.password.error.required"/>"
                data-bv-identical="true"
                data-bv-identical-field="<isprint value="#NewPasswordForm:ConfirmPassword:QualifiedName#">"
                data-bv-identical-message="<istext key="account.user.new.password.error.confirm_Password"/>"
                data-bv-regexp="true"
                data-bv-regexp-regexp="^(?=[^\s]*[a-zA-Z])(?=[^\s]*[\d])[^\s].{7,256}$"
                data-bv-regexp-message="<istext key="account.create_user.password.error.regexp"/>"
                />
```

and HTML code after pressing space.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<input id="NewPassword_Password" class="form-control" type="password" data-bv-regexp-message="The password must be at least 7 characters in length." data-bv-regexp-regexp="^(?=[^\s]*[a-zA-Z])(?=[^\s]*[\d])[^\s].{7,256}$" data-bv-regexp="true" data-bv-identical-message="The password and its confirm are not the same." data-bv-identical-field="NewPassword_ConfirmPassword" data-bv-identical="true" data-bv-notempty-message="The password is required and cannot be empty." required="" data-bv-notempty="true" placeholder="Password" name="NewPassword_Password" data-bv-field="NewPassword_Password">
<i class="form-control-feedback glyphicon-remove glyphicon" style="" data-bv-icon-for="NewPassword_Password"></i>
<small class="help-block" style="" data-bv-validator="identical" data-bv-for="NewPassword_Password" data-bv-result="INVALID">The password and its confirm are not the same.</small>
<small class="help-block" style="" data-bv-validator="notEmpty" data-bv-for="NewPassword_Password" data-bv-result="INVALID">The password is required and cannot be empty.</small>
<small class="help-block" style="" data-bv-validator="regexp" data-bv-for="NewPassword_Password" data-bv-result="INVALID">The password must be at least 7 characters in length.</small>
</div>
```

please give some input.

Answer (score 3):

You could hide them with css:

```
small.help-block {
  display: none;
}

small.help-block:first-of-type {
  display: block
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at how plugin author (Phuoc Nguyen) handles that - http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/changing-default-behaviour/#showing-one-message-each-time

Basicly the trick is to listen for validation error events and hide all error messages except the last validator check:

```
    .on('error.validator.bv', function(e, data) {
        // $(e.target)    --> The field element
        // data.bv        --> The BootstrapValidator instance
        // data.field     --> The field name
        // data.element   --> The field element
        // data.validator --> The current validator name

        data.element
            .data('bv.messages')
            // Hide all the messages
            .find('.help-block[data-bv-for="' + data.field + '"]').hide()
            // Show only message associated with current validator
            .filter('[data-bv-validator="' + data.validator + '"]').show();
    });
```

All code (I assume) is by plugin author himself - Phuoc Nguyen https://github.com/nghuuphuoc